# allowing user to add content, photos without giving access

Tags: profiles

Is it possible in wordpress to allow user to add content through editor and add some other elements like photos, country name, user name and email without giving admin access ? I want to make voting page. Where anyone can create their profile by signing up. Once they sign up they would be able to add content but admin have authority to publish it or not ?

Comment: Take a look at [`add_cap`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_cap)

Comment: how can I call add_theme_caps() function in front in page so that user can sign up for their profile and add, edit their profile content. Can you give me more detail idea?